# What is this kind of rubber band with low elasticity called?

Tags: terminology, rubber

I am looking for rubber bands that are not too elastic.

I remember with LEGO there were rubber bands used as a belt between rotating pieces:

[image]

They weren't the usual rubber bands that you can stretch much more:

[image]

Do you know what is their name?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O-rings are typically made from a firmer rubber than a rubber band.  They will stretch but not as much.  They come in all sizes, so you're going to have a shopping quest ahead of you, but "O-ring" is probably the best search term for you.

[image]

[O-Ring Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=orings&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

Answer (score 0):

The lego parts were small *drive belts*. They're used in other applications such as record players. Similar parts are available (e.g. from CPC or Maplin in the UK, Amazon or eBay everywhere).